# Nginx docker container won't proxy web app container

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, reverse-proxy, ports

I have a docker container running a web app and a docker container running Nginx:ubuntu.

The Web app container is running on port:3000 and is exposed to the outside (browser connecting to host's ip at port:3000 accesses the app)

the Nginx container is running on port 80 and is accessible from browser connecting to host's ip

the Nginx container and the web app are both connected to the same Docker network bridge. I can docker exec -it (nginx) bash and ping (web-app) on it's internal IP (172.21.0.2) and vice-versa. i can also use nmap from outside both containers and see that (nginx) has the open ports on it's internal IP of 80, and the app has the open ports of 3000.

**What isn't broken:**

Nginx is installed correctly, it just probably isn't configured correctly. 
The web app is functional and unfortunately cannot be re-configured to suit Nginx.

**What i have tried:**

Installing nginx through a docker-compose.yml, a dockerfile, an empty container>bash and manually apt-get install nginx.

I cannot include both the web app and nginx in one docker-compose file (and fix the networking issue) due to the specifics of the app's image (image is actually a node.js container and has a sub-service of the app) so trying to include both services in one docker-compose.yml just causes the compose to create nginx and an app-less node.js container.

**What i would like to do:**

create an nginx container through a dockerfile and docker run command only (to support scalability)  to proxy an already running app container through a docker network they are both connected to. i want nginx to listen on port 80, and route it to the container at port 3000. what i am confused about, is; in the nginx.conf file, do i route it to the container's internal ip of 172.21.0.2:3000, the (hostIP):3000, Localhost:3000, or 0.0.0.0:3000? my files are as follows:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM xqdocker/ubuntu-nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ##.confd IS LOCAL TO DOCKERFILE
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-nginx {
        server 172.21.0.2:3000; #WHAT DO I PUT HERE??
    }


    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }


}
```

docker run command:

```
$ docker build -t reverseproxy
$ docker run --name nginx_proxy -p 80:80 -d reverseproxy
$ docker network connect nginx_app_bridge <nginx_proxy container ID>
```

note that the app's docker-compose file has the nginx_app_bridge network specified. a docker network inspect nginx_app_bridge lists 2 connected containers at 172.21.0.2 (app) and 172.21.0.3 (nginx)

so what i'm wondering is, if both containers are running properly, can be seen from the outside, can see each other, and are on the same network bridge, why/how can nginx not route requests to the container on port :3000?

I have gone through about 40 different tutorials and stack overflow suggestions on how to fix this. I have tried so many ways to get this to work. all i'm looking for is some way to force nginx to intercept all port 80 requests to the host IP and route it to the web app.

Comment: Avoid dealing with IPs. Let the docker daemon handle DNS resolution. So for instance use `server app:3000;` for the upstream server assuming you named your service `app` (better to use something more descriptive).

Comment: does the docker daemon understand cross docker-compose.yml service names? i thought you could only reference services from a docker-compose in the upstream that composes the nginx server. the docker-compose of my app looks something like

version "2"
    service: node
        image:web-app
            <location of dockerfile for app>

<some other stuff that runs a background node.js>

it builds two images: node and web-app. only the web-app stays as a running container though

Comment: Yes you can reference a service name defined in another compose file. You just need to prefix the service name with the proper project name (the dir name by default). See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/
Keep in mind that when you start nginx, your upstream service should be up already or better, retry to reconnect to upstream.

btw, the info in the compose files gets converted into json files (in Linux they're under `/var/lib/docker/containers/cont-id/config.v2.json`). That's how the daemon can restart the containers without knowing about your compose files.